# Get multiple values of an Array inside PHP function

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

This is my code:

```
function menu_MORE (Array  $ITEMS){
 foreach ($ITEMS as $ITEM) {
  echo "<li><i class='$ITEM[icon]'></i>$ITEM[link]</li>";
}

$ITEMS = array('link' => array('Edit','Remove'),
               'icon' => array('fa fa-pencil','fa fa-trash'), );

menu_MORE($ITEMS);
```

I want the output to be:

```
<li><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Remove</li>
```

I think i need a second rule/parameter but I can't figured it out how.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anyway if you only have only two array elements, then it may be unusefull to use an array for it. But perhaps that's not the case.

Comment: I have multiple items. The exemple of my question was simplified for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is er... "inverted" -- you're doing this, where each key has multiple values:

```
$ITEMS = array(
    'link' => array('Edit','Remove'),
    'icon' => array('fa fa-pencil','fa fa-trash')
);
```

You want to do this, where you have multiple entries of items, each with a single value:

```
$ITEMS = array(
    array(
        'link' => 'Edit',
        'icon' => 'fa fa-pencil',
    ),
    array(
        'link' => 'Remove',
        'icon' => 'fa fa-trash',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Oh, was that simple... Works perfect, thank you so much!